# How can I sync my contacts' information in Empathy with Evolution address book?

Tags: evolution, empathy, sync

Evolution seems to be able to sync the contact list information in Pidgin with its address book. However, is it possible to keep contact information (i.e. display pic) in Empathy synchronized with Evolution?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is currently not possible, but recently a project was started that is supposed to tackle this problem for many applications: [libfolks](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Folks).

Comment: I'm looking forward to `libfolks` or maybe something different but similar maturing and being a standard part of our Ubuntu desktop. The uses are endless...

Answer (score 0):

The maemo distro in N900 has my skype, googletalk, facebook, gmail and phone contacts all in the same address book. I could then install a tool to look for duplicates.

Maybe have piddgen make a vcard?